# Local docker image not recognized by Kubernetes

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, rancher

I created an AWS AMI with docker and my image preloaded (docker image is 7 gigs and it takes too long to download from private registry). I am using Rancher and have set my node template to use this ami. When I run my

```
kubectl create -f command
```

I get the error that the image is not present and I don't have pull permissions. When I then ssh into the EC2 node and run

```
docker images
```

Only Rancher images show up. I know that the docker file is present with the AMI as I have launched separate instances outside of Kubernetes and have proved to myself that the docker image is present. I notice when spinning up the cluster through the Rancher UI that it appears that Docker is being reinstalled on the nodes which I believe is removing the docker image.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `ssh into the EC2 instance`, I believe you checked in the node where the pod is running and not in the master.

Also kindly check if the image pull policy is set to `Never` or `IfNotPresent` in your yaml file.

```
imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Yes you are correct it was the node that I SSH'd into. I do have imagePullPolicy set to IfNotPresent. What seems to be the case is that when the node is created Docker is being reinstalled overtop the original and is removing the image.